# Errors importing my exported CSV file from MYSQL database using PHPmyadmin

Tags: mysql, database, joomla, import, virtuemart

I am trying to export a MYSQL database from PHPmyadmin with over 800 products that uses virtuemart shopping cart. 
When I export the information from my product table selecting CVS type file it exports but it won't import the information into joomla 2.5.

The report tells me These fields have been found but are not supported by CSVI:

Does this mean that I can't export the products from MYSQL as a table, is there a way around this?

Thanks
Devanstra

Comment: What are you using the import the **.csv** file?

Comment: How are you trying to import? Are you using the CSVI extension?